# Possible mistake in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds chapter 4.1?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

I have an issue with the proof of theorem 4-5 in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds. The theorem states

> **4-5 Theorem.** The set of all
> $\varphi_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\varphi_{i_k}\quad 1\leq i_1<i_2<...<i_k\leq n$ 
> is a basis for $\Lambda^k(V)$.

Here $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n$ is the dual basis corresponding to some basis of $V$, and $\Lambda^k$ is the space of alternating k-tensors on $V$. 
Now, in the proof Spivak invokes theorem 4-1 to write for any $\omega\in\Lambda^k(V)$,
$$\omega = \sum_{i_1,...,i_k}a_{i_1,...,i_k}\varphi_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes\varphi_{i_k}. $$
Here i think the sum is supposed to be over k-tuples $1\leq i_1<...<i_k\leq n$, since the notation $\sum_{i_1,...,i_k=1}^n$ isn't used as it was previously in the chapter. But what justifies writing $\omega$ in this form? Theorem 4-1 only states that the set of all
$$\varphi_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes\varphi_{i_k}\qquad 1\leq i_1,...,i_k\leq n $$
forms a basis for $\mathcal{J}^k(V)$, the space of k-tensors on $V$. How is the sum missing so many terms?

Edit: If we assume what is meant by the author is $\sum_{i_1,...,i_k}=\sum_{i_1,...,i_k=1}^n$, then the proof doesn't work. The argument continues by writing
$$\omega = Alt(\omega) = \sum_{i_1,...,i_k} a_{i_1,...,i_k}Alt(\varphi_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes\varphi_{i_k})=\sum_{i_1,...,i_k} a_{i_1,...,i_k} C\varphi_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge \varphi_{i_k}$$
for a constant $C$ (which I think should just equal $1/k!$ ?). But this doesn't show that $\omega$ is the linear combination of the tensors in the statement of the theorem!

Comment: The sum is over all $1\leq i_1\leq n, \dots, 1\leq i_k\leq n$. There is no strict inequality among the indices. We have $\omega$ is an alternating k-tensor so in particular it is a k-tensor so it is a linear combination of those guys in the tensor product. The fact that the notation $\sum\limits_{i_1,\dots, i_k}$ is used instead of $\sum\limits_{i_1,\dots, i_k=1}^n$ is just a stylistic thing. Therefore, there are loads of terms in the sum; nothing is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had a typo in the statement of theorem 4-5, and I've also made another edit addressing your comment.

Comment: how can you say "this doesn't show that $\omega$ is the linear combination of the tensors in the statement of the theorem!"? THis is exactly what it shows. The last equal sign gives $\omega$ as a linear combination of wedges of $\phi_i$, as desired (noting that if the $i$'s repeat then the wedge is zero, so the sum is really only over increasing collections), and it is the first equality which exploits the alternating nature of $\omega$. It all fits together.

Comment: Oh I missed that since it's just glossed over in the text. Thanks.

Comment: Note btw that there is an error throughout this chapter of Spivak in the notation: it should say $\bigwedge^k(V^*)$; it should be $V^*$, not $V$. This comment is also made in the last page addenda.